# select from 2 tables when t1.id=t2.id and t1.name<>t2.name

Tags: sql

need a little help with query for oracle

there is 2 tables with **id** and **name** field

i need select id, name from 2 tables 
where id from table A is equal to id from table B 
and
name from table A not equal name from table B

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost wrote the answer as your question title...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table1
INNER JOIN
  table2
    ON  table1.id    = table2.id
    AND table1.name <> table2.name
```

Comment: ty, that was what i trying to do :)